# HTML/CSS/JS to implement Move file to trash animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, typescript

I want to provide a Move to trash action from the folder tree.

When a user clicks the delete button, I want to show an animation to move the item to trash.

Example layout.

```
+--------
|  - dir1 
|    - file1    x
|    - file2    x
|    - subDir1 
|      - file3    x
+--------
| Trash
+--------
```

Since the elements are positioned 'relative' to directory in which they are present, where as Trash is relative to the top level, I couldn't find out how to do that.

Sample code with bare minimum layout.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NaLEjx

On clicking the x icon, the file should move to the element labeled Trash.

Please let me know how to do that.